# HTTP request parameter and hearders

Tags: php, http-headers, http-parameters

Reference to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608568/alternate-of-file-get-contents-function-in-wordpress). Is there any system where I can send any type of `http` request and it can inform me that what was passed in my request like headers, post/get/put parameters and all the information? So that if there is an issue in my request I can fix it. Like my request is working fine with `file_get_contents` but not working with `wp_remote_post`.

Comment: Try `wp_remote_get`. Hope help.

Comment: Have checked that, not working. There API response was "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'"

Comment: https://requestbin.com/